# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug',org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException

Tags: java, android

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pc.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

when I create a android project. plan to run it with phone, I met follow problem

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Yesterday, I met the similar problem, it due to add multiple jar. By deleting the jar can be resolved, but today I don't add the jar in project.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.691 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

after changing the minSDK version to 16, the above is full stacktrace.

I have searched the similar problem, it might be the project structure compile sdk version and Build tool version is different from the gradle settings 
but the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: can you post full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and rebuilding. This should probably fix this issue.

If still persists try remove these lines of code:

```
dexOptions { incremental = true; preDexLibraries = false javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK }
```

Change minSdkVersion 23 to 16 and try clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying clean and rebuild the project,but it doesn't work

Comment: I've tried to remove these lines of code,and sync gradle  ,but the error is still there.

Comment: Check answer again

Comment: I just try to change minSdkVersion 23 to 16 and clean and rebuild project, but the error  still exits

Comment: Post the stack trace now after changing the SDK version

Comment: Are any of the classes above in the log are your classes?

Comment: The classes in the above log are not my classes, I've just create a android project , only create a MainActivity.

Comment: Mail me your source code to chaitanyaatkuri@gmail.com will verify it

Comment: After changing buildToolsVersion as 23.0.1, it can work now. It's strange that is it because  my phone version is android 6.0. so the buildToolVersion should be 23??  I'm not familiar with gradle.
Whatever,Thank you very much for your reply today.